# HoloViews Pandas Pivot displayed in HV Layout

Tags: python, pandas, holoviews

I have a pandas df that I have pivoted to give me the view below, which is a count of categorical data:

```
Status       Green     Red      Yellow  
Brand        
B1           20        2        10
B2           10        4         0
B3            5       10         4
```

Is there a way i can have this table converted to a hv.Table? I've tried a few different ways, including making my initial dataset a HV.Dataset, but keep getting passed with errors.

I would just like to include the datatable with its accompanying chart in a report that I am building.

Thank you in advance for any help/suggestions.

Kind regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I do something like this I get a df that looks like yours, but hv.Table() doesn't give any errors, so like this there doesn't seem to be a problem:

```
# import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

# create sample data
status = np.random.choice(['Green', 'Yellow', 'Red'], size=100)
brand = np.random.choice(['B1', 'B2', 'B3'], size=100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'brand': brand, 
                   'status': status})

# create same grouped data as in the question
grouped = df.groupby(['brand', 'status'])['status'].count().unstack().reset_index()

# create holoviews table from the grouped data
hv.Table(grouped)
```

Comment: Thank you again for you help Sander, this worked great. I wonder why I can't achieve the same effect when using df.pivot_table, but groupby does the job!

Comment: in pandas i usally prefer .groupby() and later followed by .unstack() to get a pivot table. It works nicely and i only have to remember how .groupby() works :)

Comment: Hey Sander, can i also conditionally format the cells in the in the hv.Table? Like above 10 = green. I've been able to do this in pandas using:

#Heatmap of table
def change_colours(val):
    color = 'red' if val => 10 else 'green'
    return 'color: %s' % color


but then when i try to reset the index and convert to hv.Table i get the ''Styler' object has no attribute 'reset_index'" error, dropping the reset_index i get backend doesnt suppport the format error. Just wondering if their is a way within the hv.plot options that acheives the same such as ".opts(bgcolour=)

Comment: it's maybe good to post your additional question on: https://discourse.holoviz.org/